# C++ program not writing to /dev/stdout unless running in a terminal

Tags: c++, stdout, flush

I'm sure this question is dumb but I'm not familiar with C++. Sorry in advance.

I'm working with [dvbjet](https://github.com/lightful/DVBdirect), an open source program written in C++. It's  designed to write continuously to a file, the path for which can be specified via command line arguments. But for my purposes, I want to read the output of `dvbjet` into a NodeJS script. I initially tried using a named pipe, but named pipes really don't work well in NodeJS. So I want to make dvbjet output to stdout instead of to a file.

When I launch dvbjet, (using Node's `child_process`) I'm passing in /dev/stdout as the output file path. But in NodeJS, I never see any data coming from the child processes stdout. If I use `node-pty` (which simulates a tty) to launch it then I get output, but sadly `node-pty` converts the output into a string and when I convert it back into binary (using `Buffer.from(str, 'utf8')`) the data is corrupted.

So if I run the program with /dev/stdout as a terminal, it works. But if I'm not a terminal, there's no output. I suspect it's being buffered and not flushed.

I'm trying to edit dvbjet to ensure that it flushes stdout, but because I don't know what I'm doing this is a challenge. I'm also trying to make as few changes as possible to the program, and ensure that it also still works when outputting to a regular file.

Currently, dvbjet opens the file like so:

```cpp
open(outputFile.c_str(), O_WRONLY | O_CREAT | O_TRUNC | O_APPEND, 0664
```

And writes to it like this:

```cpp
write(fd, buffer->start(), buffer->length());
```

I tried adding `flush(stdout);` after the `write()` call, but it didn't make any difference. I'm not sure sure that I could use std::flush for this, because dvbjet isn't using std ostreams.

I've also tried using the `stdbuf` command as described in [this blog post](https://joshondesign.com/2015/05/14/unbuffering) but without any success.

I tried putting `setbuf(stdout, NULL);` at the start of main, also with no luck.

I checked that the issue wasn't my NodeJS script by using the same code to run `echo hi` and check that the stdout was detected, and it was.

I tried adding the following:

```cpp
fwrite(buffer->start(), 1, buffer->length(), stdout);
fflush(stdout);
```

But it still won't write to stdout. It seems the issue is not specific to using write() with /dev/stdout. I really have no idea where to look now though.

EDIT: After looking into this further, it seems that either the open call or the write call blocks when run against /dev/stdout. So the tests I tried with flushing afterwards didn't work because that code never executed.

Comment: What about `fsync(fd);` ?

Comment: and `fclose(fd)` before that

Comment: @KamilCuk fsync(fd); on its own doesn't seem to help either.

Comment: @YSC I tried `fclose(fd)` but it's invalid, fclose takes `FILE *stream` instead of `int fd`. I tried `close(fd)` but it doesn't help either, I'm still not getting any stdout. Currently dvbjet keeps the file open for long periods of time, wouldn't constantly closing and re-opening it be inefficient anyway?

Comment: Doesn't `dvbjet /dev/stdout .... ` just work?

Comment: @KamilCuk It does, but only if the stdout stream refers to an interactive device. (I.e. a terminal)

Comment: `stdout stream refers to an interactive device` - what does fail when stdout is not an interactive device? `O_WRONLY | O_CREAT | O_TRUNC | O_APPEND` could be ok, you could change that to `O_WRONLY` just for stdout.

Comment: I think [this class](https://github.com/lightful/DVBdirect/blob/master/src/Writer.h#L65) doesn't do `close(fd);` at all.

Comment: @KamilCuk I'm hoping to avoid special-cases. Removing `O_CREAT | O_TRUNC | O_APPEND` would break things for regular files. If I'm going to use special-casing I might as well use use `fwrite()`. And yeah, it doesn't call `close(fd)` because it continues writing to the file until it's killed.